# Convert Excel spreadsheet to web service

Tags: web-services, excel

A supplier of mine is looking to share their spreadsheet-based "database" with us without providing the full original spreadsheet (for numerous reasons, not relevant here). I suggested that they setup a web service to allow us to query them programatically (after all, we just want to lookup one row at a time really), but they don't have the technical ability to do this themselves.

Is there a product that allows some kind of conversion from spreadsheet to published web service, or will it be a case that they need to simply get a developer in for a few days to do it for them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They can put the Excel file on SharePoint (as a List). SharePOint lists are exposed via an API.

Comment: That's good to know, but the supplier in question doesn't have Sharepoint I'm afraid.

Comment: Would they be willing to host relevant parts of the Excel file on Google docs? google docs too provides programmatic access and supplier can control/restrict access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with Microsoft Office Live by putting the spreadsheet on SkyDrive, and then dropping some generated html into a web-page.
see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/embed-an-excel-workbook-on-a-web-page-HA102029502.aspx

Although I am not sure about how much you can restrict access until Office 365 goes live (which will include Sharepoint).
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/cloud/cloudpowersolutions/productivity.aspx?CR_CC=200016287&WT.srch=1&CR_SCC=200016287

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the data from the spreadsheet, and provide an OData or similar service to it using WCF Data Services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601461 - video on creating a WCF data service from a non-entity framework custom data source

As far as extracting the data goes, there are Linq to Excel providers that would do this nicely, or you can look at the OpenXML API - there's numerous other ways of doing this so take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but this is still a common problem.

https://hivelink.io lets you turn your Excel spreadsheet model into a web service so people can access its functionality from a "lightweight" spreadsheet.

Basically you define the inputs and outputs in your original spreadsheet and generate a lightweight copy of the workbook and remove your macros/calculations/formulas/etc.. HiveLink connects the inputs from the lightweight spreadsheet to your master spreadsheet, which you leave running on a dedicated machine, then runs your macros and returns the results you specified back to the lightweight spreadsheet.

It gives you full control to invite users and control permissions, and a webpage to publicize and distribute from. Much cheaper than hiring developers. Sounds like what you need @SamCrawford?